# appcmd to set allowed file extension by web site not globally

Tags: windows, iis, cmd, iis-8

What needs to be done to modify this script to set allowed extensions by the website and not globally.

```
appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /+fileExtensions.[fileextension='string',allowed='true | false']
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#editing-configuration-properties You missed the URL part.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you target individual sites.

```
appcmd set config "SITE_NAME_HERE" /section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.json'].allowed:true
```